# Ruby case usage taking Array

Tags: ruby

I'm having problem with this case statement, the scenario is the follow 
`subDomainBlock` are multi-line strings coming from other function and they are like

```
"fo-ds-ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net has address 98.139.21.169
fo-ds-ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net has IPv6 address 2001:4998:58:2201::50   
Host wiki.yahoo.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)"
```

The complete function involve is

```
def data_filter(subDomainBlock) 
        line = subDomainBlock.split("\n")
            #puts  " yo soy #{line.class}"
            line.each do | choise | 
            puts "-------------------"# puts "#{choise}#{choise.class}" 
            case choise 
            when choise.include?('not found')
                nil 
            when choise.include?('has address')
                puts "tiene una di"
            when choise.include?('is an alias')
                puts "es un alias"  
            when choise.include?('IPv6')
            else
                puts choise  

            end
        end     
    end
```

I also tried to do the `#{choise.include?('XXXXXXX')}` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass a variable to the `case` condition

```
       case 
       when choise.include?('not found')
         nil 
       when choise.include?('has address')
         puts "tiene una di"
       when choise.include?('is an alias')
         puts "es un alias"  
       when choise.include?('IPv6')
       else
         puts choise  
       end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `choise` variable in `when` condition.
don't use case-when, use if-elsif

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matchers for `when` statements.

```
def data_filter(subDomainBlock) 
  line = subDomainBlock.split("\n")
  line.each do |choise| 
    case choise 
    when /not found/
      nil 
    when /has address/
      puts "tiene una di"
    when /is an alias/
      puts "es un alias"  
    when /IPv6/
    else
      puts choise  
    end
  end     
end
```